# T(1)=1 is a boundary condition of the recurrence $T(n)=2T(\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor)+n$. Does there exist any other boundary condition of the recurrence?

Tags: algorithms

Section 4.3 of "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition
By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein" uses the following recurrence as an example to illustrate the substitution method.

$T(n) = 2T(\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor)+n \tag{4.19}$

That section says

> Let us assume, for the sake of argument, that T(1) = 1 is the sole boundary condition of the recurrence.

In reality, does there exist any other boundary condition of the recurrence (4.19)?

Comment: Actual boundary condition(s) of the recurrence is dependent on the actual problem at hand.

Comment: Instead of T(1) = 1, you can let T(1) = c for any c, obviously with different results. You pick whatever is most realistic. Then T(2) = 2c+2, T(3) = 2c+3, T(4) = 4c+8, T(5)=4c+9 etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you specify $T(1)$, the recurrence determines $T(n)$ for all $n \geq 2$. The value of $T(1)$ itself is arbitrary.

Given $n \geq 1$, construct a sequence of integers as follows. The starting point is $n_0 = n$. If $n_i \geq 2$, then $n_{i+1} = \lfloor n_i/2 \rfloor$. The sequence stops once $n_\ell = 1$. You can check that $\ell = \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$. Unrolling the recurrence, we have
$$
T(n) = n_0 + 2n_1 + 4n_2 + \cdots + 2^{\ell-1}n_{\ell-1} + 2^\ell T(1).
$$
Therefore if we define $T_C(n)$ to be the solution to the recurrence with initial condition $T_C(1) = C$, then
$$
T(n) = T_0(n) + 2^\ell T(1).
$$
Also, $n/2 < 2^\ell \leq n$. Therefore the choice of $T(1)$ only affects the solution by an additive factor of $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Thank you! I guess $n$ represents the input size and $T(n)$ denotes the (theoretical) running time of the algorithm being analyzed. So, $n$ might range from 0 to any large integer. let $n_0 = n=1,000,000$, what does $n_{1} = \lfloor n_0/2 \rfloor = 500,000$ mean?

Comment: I am just defining a sequence of integers: $n_0 = n$, $n_1 = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, $n_2 = \bigl\lfloor \lfloor n/2 \rfloor /2 \bigr\rfloor$, and so on.

Comment: In the actual application, $n_i$ is the size of the input in recursive calls at depth $i$ of the recursion tree.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you please explain a bit about the relation of $T(n) = T(n_0) + T(n_1) + … + 2^\ell T(1)$ and the result of "unrolling the recurrence" in you answer? In the equation I just gave, $T(n_0)$ denotes the running time of the root of the recursion tree and $T(n)$ denotes overall running time.

Comment: I’m afraid you’ll have to work it out on your own.

Comment: In other words, does the first term on the right hand in my equation, that is, $T(n_0)$ mean the same as the one $n_0$ in yours, in the context of running time?

Comment: It’s the value of the function $T$ at the input $n_0$. No more, no less.